# Wildfly 9 ignores web.xml entries

Tags: java, maven, jboss, wildfly, java-ee-7

I use IntelliJ, Maven, the Maven Wildfly Plugin and a Wildfly 9 Server in my project. I created a `web.xml` in my `WEB-INF` directory. But the entries in my `web.xml` are all ignored by the Wildfly Server. For example the displayname is not displayed in the browser. The War-Files contains the `web.xml`

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
         version="3.0">

    <display-name>JavaEE 7 Demo</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.faces</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

For the sake of completeness my `pom.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
    JBoss, Home of Professional Open Source
    Copyright 2013, Red Hat, Inc. and/or its affiliates, and individual
    contributors by the @authors tag. See the copyright.txt in the
    distribution for a full listing of individual contributors.

    Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
    you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
    You may obtain a copy of the License at
    http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
    Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
    distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
    WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
    See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
    limitations under the License.
-->
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>eu.henok</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo-javaee7</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>WildFly Quickstarts: demo-javaee7</name>
    <description>A starter Java EE 7 webapp project for use on JBoss WildFly / WildFly, generated from the jboss-javaee6-webapp archetype</description>

    <url>http://wildfly.org</url>
    <licenses>
        <license>
            <name>Apache License, Version 2.0</name>
            <distribution>repo</distribution>
            <url>http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.html</url>
        </license>
    </licenses>

    <properties>
        <!-- Explicitly declaring the source encoding eliminates the following 
            message: -->
        <!-- [WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered 
            resources, i.e. build is platform dependent! -->
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>

        <!-- JBoss dependency versions -->
        <version.wildfly.maven.plugin>1.0.2.Final</version.wildfly.maven.plugin>

        <!-- Define the version of the JBoss BOMs we want to import to specify 
            tested stacks. -->
        <version.jboss.bom>8.2.1.Final</version.jboss.bom>

        <!-- other plugin versions -->
        <version.compiler.plugin>3.1</version.compiler.plugin>
        <version.surefire.plugin>2.16</version.surefire.plugin>
        <version.war.plugin>2.5</version.war.plugin>

        <!-- maven-compiler-plugin -->
        <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
    </properties>


    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <!-- JBoss distributes a complete set of Java EE 7 APIs including a Bill
                of Materials (BOM). A BOM specifies the versions of a "stack" (or a collection) 
                of artifacts. We use this here so that we always get the correct versions 
                of artifacts. Here we use the jboss-javaee-7.0-with-tools stack (you can
                read this as the JBoss stack of the Java EE 7 APIs, with some extras tools
                for your project, such as Arquillian for testing) and the jboss-javaee-7.0-with-hibernate
                stack you can read this as the JBoss stack of the Java EE 7 APIs, with extras
                from the Hibernate family of projects) -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.wildfly.bom</groupId>
                <artifactId>jboss-javaee-7.0-with-tools</artifactId>
                <version>${version.jboss.bom}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.wildfly.bom</groupId>
                <artifactId>jboss-javaee-7.0-with-hibernate</artifactId>
                <version>${version.jboss.bom}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>

        <!-- First declare the APIs we depend on and need for compilation. All 
            of them are provided by JBoss WildFly -->

        <!-- Import the CDI API, we use provided scope as the API is included in 
            JBoss WildFly -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.enterprise</groupId>
            <artifactId>cdi-api</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Import the Common Annotations API (JSR-250), we use provided scope 
            as the API is included in JBoss WildFly -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.annotation</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-annotations-api_1.2_spec</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Import the JAX-RS API, we use provided scope as the API is included 
            in JBoss WildFly -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxrs-api</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Import the JPA API, we use provided scope as the API is included in 
            JBoss WildFly -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Import the EJB API, we use provided scope as the API is included in 
            JBoss WildFly -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.ejb</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-ejb-api_3.2_spec</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- JSR-303 (Bean Validation) Implementation -->
        <!-- Provides portable constraints such as @Email -->
        <!-- Hibernate Validator is shipped in JBoss WildFly -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Import the JSF API, we use provided scope as the API is included in 
            JBoss WildFly -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Now we declare any tools needed -->

        <!-- Annotation processor to generate the JPA 2.0 metamodel classes for 
            typesafe criteria queries -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Annotation processor that raising compilation errors whenever constraint 
            annotations are incorrectly used. -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator-annotation-processor</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Needed for running tests (you may also use TestNG) -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Optional, but highly recommended -->
        <!-- Arquillian allows you to test enterprise code such as EJBs and Transactional(JTA) 
            JPA from JUnit/TestNG -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>arquillian-junit-container</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.protocol</groupId>
            <artifactId>arquillian-protocol-servlet</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <!-- Maven will append the version to the finalName (which is the name 
            given to the generated war, and hence the context root) -->
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${version.war.plugin}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <!-- Java EE 7 doesn't require web.xml, Maven needs to catch up! -->
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <!-- The WildFly plugin deploys your war to a local WildFly container -->
            <!-- To use, run: mvn package wildfly:deploy -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.wildfly.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>wildfly-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${version.wildfly.maven.plugin}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <hostname>${wildfly-hostname}</hostname>
                    <port>${wildfly-port}</port>
                    <username>${wildfly-username}</username>
                    <password>${wildfly-password}</password>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <!-- The default profile skips all tests, though you can tune it to run 
                just unit tests based on a custom pattern -->
            <!-- Seperate profiles are provided for running all tests, including Arquillian 
                tests that execute in the specified container -->
            <id>default</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>${version.surefire.plugin}</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <skip>true</skip>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>

        <profile>
            <id>wildfly-local</id>
            <properties>
                <wildfly-home>E:\dev\wildfly-9.0.1.Final</wildfly-home>
                <wildfly-hostname>127.0.0.1</wildfly-hostname>
                <wildfly-port>9990</wildfly-port>
                <wildfly-username>admin</wildfly-username>
                <wildfly-password>admin</wildfly-password>
            </properties>
        </profile>

        <profile>

            <!-- An optional Arquillian testing profile that executes tests
                in your WildFly instance -->
            <!-- This profile will start a new WildFly instance, and execute the
                test, shutting it down when done -->
            <!-- Run with: mvn clean test -Parq-wildfly-managed -->
            <id>arq-wildfly-managed</id>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.wildfly</groupId>
                    <artifactId>wildfly-arquillian-container-managed</artifactId>
                    <scope>test</scope>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </profile>

        <profile>
            <!-- An optional Arquillian testing profile that executes tests
                in a remote WildFly instance -->
            <!-- Run with: mvn clean test -Parq-wildfly-remote -->
            <id>arq-wildfly-remote</id>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.wildfly</groupId>
                    <artifactId>wildfly-arquillian-container-remote</artifactId>
                    <scope>test</scope>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </profile>

        <profile>
            <!-- When built in OpenShift the 'openshift' profile will be used when 
                invoking mvn. -->
            <!-- Use this profile for any OpenShift specific customization your app 
                will need. -->
            <!-- By default that is to put the resulting archive into the 'deployments' 
                folder. -->
            <!-- http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-building-for-different-environments.html -->
            <id>openshift</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>${version.war.plugin}</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>deployments</outputDirectory>
                            <warName>ROOT</warName>
                            <webappDirectory>${project.build.directory}/exp</webappDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>

    </profiles>
</project>
```

Answer (score 2):

as per the Servlet 2.3 spec (back in 2000):

> The display-name element contains a short name that is intended to be
>   displayed by GUI tools

Nothing to do with the browser

Comment: And where and how can I configure the name displayed in my browser?

Comment: in your facelet templates

Comment: a yeah i was confused a bit :) thanks you for your help. i normally work with tomcat application servers